# Convert HTML to MHTML

Tags: c#, html, windows-mobile, compact-framework, mhtml

Is there any way to convert HTML and its associated images to MHTML in windows mobile?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article that explains how to do it in ASP.NET, maybe you can adapt it or grab some ideas for your environment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/aspnethtml2mht.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Here is a class I wrote to do this: https://github.com/DavidBenko/MHTML-to-HTML-Decoding-in-C-Sharp.

[Here is a go through on how to use it.](http://prndl.us/mhtml-html-decoding-c-sharp/)

Feel free to fork it for your needs.

Comment: Not useful: Converts ***HTML to MHTML***, not _MHTML to HTML_